# Sorting n lists whith no coincidences

Tags: algorithm, sorting

(This is my very first question, if I'm doing something wrong, please tell me :))

I have n lists whose elements have an integer attribute (unique per list) and a duration in seconds.

I have to sort these lists with no coioncidence of elements with the same attribute in time, and opitimize the total duration (the duration of the longest list in time).

If there is no alternative, a gap of time is inserted until the duration of an other list element is over.

I developed an algorithm which selects an element from the longest in time adding all of the same attribute in every list

Example (edited): Every element is represented as (int att, duration time)

```
List 1: (1,20) (2,13) (3,15)
List 2: (1,14) (2,20) (3,14)

Optimum sorting: 
    List 1: (1,20) (3,15) (Gap,1) (2,13)  List 1 duration: 20+15+1+13   = 49
    List 2: (3,16) (2,20) (1,14)          List 2 duration: 16+20+14     = 50
    Total time: MAX(49,50) = 50

My algorithm:
    Sorting by duration to select candidates: 1 (20+14 = 34 seconds), 2 (13+20 = 33 seconds), 3 (15+14 = 29 secs)

    Final sorting:
        List 1: (1,20) (2,13) (3,15)            List 1 duration: 20+13+15    = 48
        List 2: (2,20) (1,14) (Gap,14) (3,16)   List 2 duration: 20+14+14+16 = 64
        Total time: MAX(48,64) = 64
```

Anyone knows an algorithm which optimize the sorting?

If it is not well expressed please let me know

Sorry for my English :_)

**(Edited)**

I found a [Thesis](http://www.dm.uba.ar/materias/optimizacion/2008/1/tesis.PDF) in Spanish presenting the problem and suggesting some solutions. It's a Job Shop Scheduling problem, as AShelly pointed out in a comment.

Comment: Have you looked up one of the hundreds of sorting algorithms that exist? The web is full of resources.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried but I didn't find any... Maybe si too specific

Comment: @Carcigenicate But I don't need only sorting, I need to accomplish the requirements... Maybe it's a question too complicated and too specific to be here

Comment: Not completely sure I understood the constraints; but why can't you do List1:(1,20)(3,15)(gap,1)(2,13) and List2:(3,16)(2,20)(1,14)? Isn't that a better solution?

Comment: @Henry Yes :_) It's better solution than the "optimum" i got, in fact that is the optimum. I proceed to edit, thank you! :)

Comment: maybe don't sort them at all, but save the duration of each list, and the current max. Then when you add item to a list, adjust the list duration and compare with the max.

Comment: @Slai I've been thinking maybe with backtracking I could explore all the posibilities but with the gaps, the possibilities tends to infinity, don't they?

Comment: You can first backtrack over the order only (thus generating permutations for each list), without using gaps. Afterwards, gaps should be added until the constraint is satisfied. But even now, when the order is fixed, optimizing the gaps seems difficult. One possible approach is to backtrack more, deciding for each moment with conflicting id's which list will stay still, and inserting gaps into the others.

Comment: @qwertyman Thank you! I think too the key is the gaps and I think the backtrack is going to be the most of the algorithm time. I'll try your idea :)

Comment: What are the constraints: number of IDs, number of lists?

Comment: I believe this is an instance of the [Job Shop Scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling) problem

Comment: @user58697 The number or ID's now it's 10 aprox. and the number of lists is 8 but it will be higher in the future

Comment: @AShelly It seems similar, I'll take a look, thank you!

Comment: In your example, called "Optimum sorting," why is there no gap added after the first element in List 2? Or is a gap only added at the very end?

Comment: @גלעד ברקן the gaps are added when we can't put an element because there is a conflict in other list, we try to avoid them. If we can use the time, we use it, is it clear? ;)

Comment: (3, 15), (1, 20), (2, 13) and (1, 14), (2, 20), (3, 14) would be better, requires no gap. If the number of attributes per list is bigger than the number of lists then it is likely that such a solution exists.